# What is the exact value/role of pronoun "it" in this context?

Tags: pronouns, dummy-pronouns

In ["Why Haven’t We Made IT Safer to Breathe in Classrooms"](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/08/09/opinion/air-filter-covid-smoke-schools.html), what is the actual role the pronoun "it" plays on this sentence? What does "it" refer to?

What do I need "it" for if I can read the sentence perfectly without the use of "it"?

Answer (score 3):

It's a [dummy subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun).

English requires an expressed subject in many contexts, even where there is no logical subject.

One of those is in an infinitive clause that is the object of *make* (= compel, bring about). The clause is required to be *[subject] [infinitive] [objects/complements]* and if there is no logical subject then we use the dummy subject "it".

Comment: OR rephrase to something like *Why haven’t we made **breathing in classrooms** safer?*